# Supervisor is not starting up

Tags: docker, supervisord, cloudera-cdh, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am following cloudera cdh4 installation guide.

My base file

```
FROM ubuntu:precise

RUN apt-get update -y
#RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | \
debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer

#Checking java version
RUN java -version
```

My hadoop installation file

java_ubuntu is the image build from my base file.

```
FROM java_ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/precise/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb > cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb
RUN dpkg -i cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb
RUN curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/archive.key | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo

#Check for /etc/hadoop/conf.pseudo.mrl to verfiy hadoop packages
RUN echo "dhis"  
RUN dpkg -L hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo
```

Supervisor part
  hadoop_ubuntu is the image build from my hadoop installation docker file

```
FROM hadoop_ubuntu:latest

USER hdfs
RUN hdfs namenode -format

USER root

RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN echo "[supervisord] nodameon=true  [program=namenode] command=/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode -D" > /etc/supervisorconf.d

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Program is successfully build. But namenode is not starting up? How to use supervisor?

Comment: you should `docker exec -it hadoop_ubuntu:latest /bin/bash` and check, what processes run, what is in your supervisor file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your config in `/etc/supervisorconf.d` and I don't believe that's the right location.

It should be `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf` instead.

Also it's easier to maintain if you make a file locally and then use the COPY instruction to put it in the image.

Then as someone mentioned you can connect to the container after it's running (`docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash`) and then run `supervisorctl` to see what's running and what might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks ryan. I 'll try the same and let you know asap.

Comment: i think you can put config anywhere as long as you tell it? 
`supervisord -c /my/path/supervisord.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need line breaks in your supervisor.conf.   Try hand crafting one and COPY it into your dockerfile for testing.

[Docker and supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/)